# Call controller method on ui-router state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building part of an application where an admin can add or remove product categories. For navigation, I'm using Angular's ui-router. The admin has subviews, which are reached via the dot notation method (admin.category, admin.product, etc).

When I change state to the `admin.category` section, I need to call a method in my AdminController to fetch some data from the backend api. However, I'm not completely sure how to achieve this.

relevant code:

```
.state('admin', {

url: '/admin',
templateUrl: 'app/admin/dashboard.html',
controller: 'AdminController',
resolve: {

    userPass: function(adminService) {

        return adminService.loggedIn();
    }
}

})
.state('admin.category', {

url: '/category',
templateUrl: 'app/admin/category.html',
controller: 'AdminController',
onEnter: function() {

   //I want to call this in the AdminController 
   parentCategories();

}

});
```

Comment: usually sharing code and data is better done with a service in angular, can't you move the things you want to call inside your adminService?

Comment: I can move it into a service, but I can't figure out a way to easily grab the data only when the category state is loaded. Passing the data with resolve means I need to set that variable on every admin state (even though it's unnecessary) . Setting the parentCategories variable in the controller, means it's getting called even though it may never be needed

Comment: I don't understand: if you only need it in the category state, why don't you put it in a resolve of this admin.category state then? Basically: if you need it everywhere: put the resolve in the parent state, if you need it only at one (or a few) specfic child-states, put the resolve on the specific child states.